# Install confusion MongoDB with Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to install a node/mongo app for the first time, specifically https://github.com/nature/pa11y-dashboard to a virtual host on my Digital Ocean Ubuntu droplet.

I've successfully installed all the dependencies, but I'm not sure about the MongoDb configuration. In the /config directory there is a development.json sample which the instructions seem to imply would be fine to use locally.

```
{
    "port": 4000,
    "noindex": true,
    "readonly": false,

    "webservice": {
            "database": "mongodb://localhost/pa11y-webservice-dev",
            "host": "0.0.0.0",
            "port": 3000,
            "cron": "0 30 0 * * *"
    }
```

}

Running `NODE_ENV=development nodejs .` outputs the following error.

```
connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
visit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0

pa11y-dashboard started
mode: development
uri:  http://0.0.0.0:4000

pa11y-webservice started
mode: development
uri:  http://0.0.0.0:3000

/var/www/website.com/public/node_modules/pa11y-webservice/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:242
    throw message;
          ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at __executeInsertCommand (/var/www/website.com/public/node_modules/pa11y-webservice/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1829:12)
at Db._executeInsertCommand (/var/www/website.com/public/node_modules/pa11y-webservice/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1930:5)
at /var/www/website.com/public/node_modules/pa11y-webservice/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1442:27
at /var/www/website.com/public/node_modules/pa11y-webservice/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1560:7
at /var/www/website.com/public/node_modules/pa11y-webservice/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:162:16
at commandHandler (/var/www/website.com/public/node_modules/pa11y-webservice/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:706:16)
at /var/www/website.com/public/node_modules/pa11y-webservice/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1806:9
at Server.Base._callHandler (/var/www/website.com/public/node_modules/pa11y-webservice/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:442:41)
at /var/www/website.com/public/node_modules/pa11y-webservice/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:485:18
at MongoReply.parseBody (/var/www/website.com/public/node_modules/pa11y-webservice/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
```

Looking at the Mongo shell no db for pa11y-webservice-dev shows up, but from what I read that is typical until data is pushed there.

Any help getting this set up would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to run `grunt test` in the root directory

Comment: @Michelem, that definitely seems to be part of the issue. I don't get any errors when running `grunt test` or even `grunt version` just nothing... even though I've should have installed it with `npm install grunt-cli` obviously something didn't work correctly on Ubuntu.

Comment: IMO using Mongoose is easier than Raw MongoDB.

Comment: Well I got grunt to work now, but now I'm still getting errors. `grunt start-test` only responds with `Running "nodemon:test" (nodemon) task
Fatal error: Error`. Not super helpful (at least for me).